# sp_grantdbaccess cannot be run in a stored proc owned by DBO?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but... I have a SQL Server 2000 database with a stored procedure that is owned by DBO. This stored procedure is calling sp_grantdbaccess, which can be run by DBO, according to MS documentation. and I'm running a Windows user that belongs to a database role that has execute permission on this stored procedure.

If I understand ownership chaining correctly (which I obviously don't), I should be able to run this stored procedure, since it is run with impersonation as DBO.

But alas, it is telling me that the user doesn't have permission to run sp_grantdbaccess.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Have any `DENY` permissions been set for the proc by any chance?

Comment: no deny permission on this stored proc, only GRANT EXECUTE.

Comment: Any other `DENY` permissions on the group you're a member of?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message in the question?

Comment: There are no deny permissions anywhere.

The exact error is 

"Cannot alter the role 'db_datareader', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

The role db_datareader obviously exists because it is a built-in database role. It is so weird to me that you can GRANT LOGIN and GRANT DB ACCESS being securityadmin and db_accessadmin, but you have to actually be DBO to use ADDROLEMEMBER.